# Activity Feed with User Likes

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a database with 4 tables (at the moment)

Tables : `Activity`, `Follow`, `Likes`, `Users`

I've managed to get the activity feed working with who the user follows but i'm struggling to try and get the Likes table working.

Is it possible to create an extra column in the query to check the likes table and show a `true` or `false` if a user has previously liked that post.
This is what I have as my current query.

```
INSERT INTO Likes (likeID, Usr_ID, activityID) VALUES (NULL, 1, 14);
UPDATE activity A SET A.likes = A.likes+1
  WHERE (A.Activity_ID = (SELECT activityID FROM Likes WHERE Usr_ID = '1' ORDER BY likeID DESC LIMIT 1));
UPDATE users U SET U.likes = U.likes+1
  WHERE (U.User_ID = (SELECT UsrID FROM activity WHERE activity_ID = (SELECT activityID FROM Likes WHERE Usr_ID = '1' ORDER BY likeID DESC LIMIT 1)))
```

Edit: This is the code I have when a post is liked.

This is the code I have for the feed

```
SELECT Activity_ID, UsrID, firstName, lastName, Date, Time, Details, Likes, Image FROM activity AS a
INNER JOIN follow AS f1 
ON a.UsrID = f1.followingID
INNER JOIN users as u
ON a.UsrID = u.User_ID
WHERE f1.followerID = 1
```

Edit: To try and clear up some what I'm trying to do. Never explained myself very well.

I am trying trying to get my activity feed for each user, which I have achieved. My code looks at the followers table, find what users the current user is following and shows only the following users feed. What I want to do is get output to show what posts the current user has liked. I have created a table to show what user has liked what post, but i'm stuck on how to output this with the above code.

Comment: Why do the `Users` and `Activity` tables have a `Likes` column?

Comment: Users - User list with 'Like' count (similar to reddit karma) then each post has individual likes.

Comment: Is this an optimization?  Regardless, what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'll update. I've not explained myself. apologies.

Comment: I would just have 3 individual queries.  `select blah from users join x where users.id=123`, where `x` is each interaction a person can have.

Comment: Right ok, I'm very new to any form of SQL so i'm still trying to get to grasps with things. I am using this with a PHP page to output to JSON, from what i've read it looks a bit of a challenge to use multiple statements. I think.

Comment: You don't need to do multiple statements in one query, have 3 sets of code in PHP to do each individual query.  (Query the database 3 times)